# How to detect when a div inside a table cell is clicked on?

Tags: jquery

I have a div inside a table cell. When I click in the table cell on the div, the click event isn't trigged, it seems like that table cell is on top of the div? I have tried adjusting the z-index to no avail.

Example row:

```
<tr ><td><div class="test" style='width:64px; height:22px; margin:0 auto; z-index:1000'></div></td></tr>
```

Example jquery:

```
$('.test').click(function(){
        console.log($(this), 'this');
    });
```

**Update**: The div in my table row is added dynamically after the document is loaded and the jquery code is in the `.ready` part of my code perhaps that is why?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/724LT/ Works fine.

Comment: That looks correct. Is the div by any chance added dynamically after the DOM has loaded? In that case you will have to use `.on()` instead of `.click()`.

Comment: It [actually works](http://jsfiddle.net/MWwQ4/), so may we see more code, please?

Comment: Works here - http://jsfiddle.net/47UJR/

Comment: It seems that it's working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AwyAr/1/

Comment: @mgraph: *"click not working if the div element is empty"* No, that's not correct. The `div` doesn't have to have content. It does have to be two-dimensional, but the OP has ensured that with the styling.

Comment: The div in my table row is added dynamically after the document is loaded and the jquery code is in the .ready part of my code perhaps that is why?

Comment: @Hardworker: That comment completely changes the question. I've moved it into the question for you, and answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to your question is in your recent comment:

> The div in my table row is added dynamically after the document is loaded and the jquery code is in the .ready part of my code perhaps that is why?

When you run your code, which hooks up the handler directly on elements, it will hook the `click` event **only** on elements matching the selector *that already exist*. Elements you add later won't be hooked up.

If you want your code to handle elements that are added later, you probably want to use *event delegation*. jQuery supports this via the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function or (if you're using 1.7 or later) the delegating form of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
// Using `delegate`:
$("selector_for_some_container").delegate(".test", "click", function() {
    console.log($(this), 'this');
});

// Using `on` (v1.7 or later, note that the arguments are in a different order):
$("selector_for_some_container").on("click", ".test", function() {
    console.log($(this), 'this');
});
```

What those do is hook the `click` event on some container (in your case you might use the table), and when the click reaches that container, jQuery checks to see if it traveled through an element matching the selector you give. If so, jQuery fires the event as though you'd hooked click on the element itself.

Here's an example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ihezah) | [live source](http://jsbin.com/ihezah/edit)):

HTML:

```
<p>The "static" div below exists before we hook up our
event handlers; the "dynamic" one is adding after.
Click each of them to see which handlers fire.</p>
<table id="theTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><div class='test' style='width:64px; height:22px; margin:0 auto; z-index:1000'>static</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="target"></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // Note that the div doesn't exist yet, so this won't
  // hook it up
  $(".test").click(function() {
    display("Direct click handled on " +
            this.innerHTML
           );
  });

  // This form uses event delegation. Note that the div
  // still doesn't exist.
  $("#theTable").delegate(".test", "click", function() {
    display("Delegated click handled on " +
            this.innerHTML
           );
  });

  // Add the div
  $("#target").html(
    "<div class='test' style='width:64px; height:22px; margin:0 auto; z-index:1000'>dynamic</div>"
  );

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

Alternately, of course, you can always hook up the event on the element when you're adding it. But if you're adding and subtracting elements from a container, event delegation is *usually* (not always) the way to handle events on them.